# PyPIパッケージでのClassifierの書き方について

Tags: python, sphinx, pypi

作成したPyPIパッケージについて、次のようなケースを想定します。

- python3のみ対応
- ただし、現状テストできているのはpython3.8のみ

この場合のClassifierの指定は次の通りでどうでしょうか？

```
Programming Language :: Python :: 3
Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

良さそうです。

私自身は `:: Only` を付けていません。
https://github.com/jazzband/django-redshift-backend/blob/master/setup.cfg

代わりにClassifier以外で `python_requires = >=3.6, <4` のようにPythonバージョンを指定しています。
https://packaging.python.org/guides/dropping-older-python-versions/